# SSRS - prepared query executed with ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, reporting-services, dataset

Is possible to get result from prepared statement from **ORACLE database** like similar example below for SQL Server?

SQL SERVER:
I have created parameter with name **WHERE** for using of "where" condition, for example

```
FirstName = 'Peter'
```

And here is the query defined in dataset:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
    set @query= 'SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2012].[dbo].[DimEmployee] WHERE ' + @WHERE
    exec(@query)
```

And that works correctly!

So my question is, whether is possible replicate it for ORACLE database, I tested something like this below, but it doesn't work.

```
declare
  sql_query varchar2(150);
begin
  sql_query := 'SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM DimEmployee WHERE ';

  sql_query := sql_query || ' ' || @WHERE;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql_query);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem... Just use string concatination:

```
 declare
  sql_query varchar2(150);
  where varchar2(1000);
begin
  sql_query := 'SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM DimEmployee t WHERE ';
  where := 't.FirstName like ''John Doe''';
  sql_query := sql_query || ' ' || where;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql_query);
end;
/
```